# Single query for nested comments

Tags: mysql

In an effort to create an efficient method for displaying nested comments I am hoping that it's possible to do with one query.

Simplified comment table

```
CREATE TABLE comment (
comment_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
date int unsigned,
parent_id int unsigned,
comment text);
```

To clarify, comments are to be ordered by `date` ASC. If a comment has a `parent_id` which is not null, that means it is a nested comment. This `parent_id` refers to said comments' parent `comment_id`.

This latter part is where I am having difficulty. Can anyone help me come up with a single mysql query to do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should cater to your second need in an efficient way:

```
CREATE TABLE comment(
comment_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
date INT UNSIGNED,
parent_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
commend TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY fk_parent(parent_id)
REFERENCES comment(comment_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE RESTRICT)
```

You just want to ensure that a child comment isn't inserted before a parent comment because of the foreign key reference.

However, when it comes to ordering your table by date, the MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax includes no such functionality and I think an effective implementation would be to simply ORDER BY while querying. Bear in mind, however, if you do choose to alter the table at a later stage and order it by the date, that any operations post this alteration will not adhere to this order. Specifically:

```
ALTER TABLE comment ORDER BY date ASC
```

will only order the present data in your table and not any subsequent data entering it.

Also, consider using a DATE data type instead of int, depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the reply. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with using FOREIGN KEY and the implications of doing so (effect on my table / size / efficiency / unrelated queries to said table) and will require a little more time to research these considerations. I was hoping there'd be some way to cleanly do this in a single query without resorting to other methods. Can I ask if you believe this is one solution or the most effective / efficient solution out of all the possible ones? Thank you again.

Comment: A Foreign Key provides nothing but surety in your code that the parent comment exists in the database. It also makes for easier querying when you want to find said parent comment. As far as ordering goes, as long as you index the date column, I don't think you need to resort to ALTER TABLE because ordering while querying should be cheap. In general though, it's good to understand indexing and constraints on databases for effective management. Hope this helped!

Comment: @YashTD How to write the query to select the top 10 parents and its child in a single query?